# How to read until seeing ',' from Text C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read lines from the text until the comma and I am going to use the both side of the comma.First one for minute,other part for the angle.the text like :

```
0.34,34.3
0.46,32.5
0.56,36.7
```

I am trying to do seperate these lines but It didnt work like this;

```
  String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("turn.txt");
        string[] parts = new String[]{""};
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            parts = line.Split(',');
            //Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        foreach (string part in parts)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(part);
        }
```

The output is giving only the first and last line of the "time" side . How can I get all of two value?

Comment: Just declare parts as `string[] parts`. No need to initialize it.

Comment: Please make it more clear. Stop what? You already had read all lines. Stop printing? When? When one line contains comma? Just add `if (parts.Length > 1) break;` inside your first `foreach`. BTW this will print only first line with comma. If you want to print them all you have to make `parts` a `List<string>` (adding `Split()` result or `line` itself to such collection).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It will print the *last* line.

Comment: @dodotu Obviously! You first read ALL the lines, for every line you replace what's in `parts`. Only after that has been done (and the last line has been read) you print the contents of `parts` - which outputs what is in the last line...

Comment: @CodesInChaos I mean: "this" = code in comment (with `break`).

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted does not make sence, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do tho.

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("turn.txt");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        String[] parts = line.Split(',');
        //Console.WriteLine(line);
        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part);
        }
    }
```

What your code is doing, is that it will only ever run through the parts of the last line, because you only get to the second `foreach` when the first one is done, meaning the last line of the text file.

If you on the other hand want to read lines until you reach a line with a comma, you're looking for something like this instead:

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("turn.txt");
String[] parts = new String[] {};
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        parts = line.Split(',');
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            break;
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(part);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem , parts will only contain the parts from last line. since you set it each time.
parts should be an Array of arrays, and a more .netish way to do this is by using list

```
    List<string[]> parts = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        parts.add(line.Split(','));
    }

    foreach (string[] part in parts)
    {
       foreach (string p in part)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(p);
       }
    }
```

Comment: `System.String[] System.String[] System.String[]`...arrays don't have an overloaded `ToString()` to print their content anyway +1 concept is clear! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andreas's Answer, you can make array of array with 2D array like this:

```
string[][] parts
```

The first dimension of 2D array must have the length of line count from the text. The second dimension store string in the line splitted by ',' character.

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("turn.txt");
string[][] parts = new String[lines.Length][];
int counter = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    parts[counter++] = line.Split(',');
}
```

to show the result you can use Andreas answer to do that:

```
foreach (string[] part in parts)
{
    foreach (string p in part)
    {
        Console.Write(p + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```